# select case with Concatenated String in vb

Tags: vb.net

Here is my code about college admission, but it won't run.

```
Public Class College_Admission

Private Sub btnResult_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnResult.Click
    Dim score, rank As Integer
    score = txtScore.Text
    rank = txtRank.Text
    Select Case score And rank
        Case Is >= 90 and  >= 25
            lblResult.Text = "Congratulation, you can apply for this college!"
        Case Is >= 89 and >= 50
            lblResult.Text = "Congratulation, you can apply for this college!"
        Case Is >= 70 and  >= 75
            lblResult.Text = "Congratulation, you can apply for this college!"
        Case Else
            lblResult.Text = "Sorry, you can not apply this college."

    End Select
End Sub
End Class
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: `Select Case score And rank` I'm not sure the syntax works like that.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cy37t14y.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Select for this. Because you have two conditions to check, it won't work.  Just do this:

```
If (score >= 90 And rank >= 25) Or (score >= 89 And rank >= 50) Or (score >= 70 And rank >= 75) Then
    lblResult.Text = "Congratulations, you can apply to this college!"
Else
    lblResult.Text = "Sorry, you cannot apply to this college."
End If
```

Comment: + 1 You beat me to it :)

Comment: I was just curious to know why did you say `Select case` wont work in his current situation.? It will work. Have a look at my answer below.

Comment: Well, yes, `Select Case true` *works*, a bit obscurely, but `Select x and y` doesn't.  It doesn't make sense to use Select for what is really just an if/else scenario.

Comment: Who downvoted this? `it won't work` is obviously correct: push wrong syntax ... receive wrong answer. `If/Else` is the most correct.